# what is the best file utility cleanup tool for windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

question is in the subject . .  i need to find space on my PC so i want to get rid of unused junk

Comment: As in programs or large files hidden deep within the system?

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend **[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)**:

> CCleaner is a freeware system
>   optimization, privacy and cleaning
>   tool. It removes unused files from
>   your system - allowing Windows to run
>   faster and freeing up valuable hard
>   disk space. It also cleans traces of
>   your online activities such as your
>   Internet history. Additionally it
>   contains a fully featured registry
>   cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

While CCleaner that Sathya mentions is good for cleaning up trash and such, I think you will get the most space from uninstalling software packages you no longer use (Photoshop for home use anyone?)  and throwing away large, unused files.

I would recommend **[TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)** (or anything similar) to help you detect sometimes very large files hidden deep within your system, which you have long since forgotten about. It will also tell you which applications take up way too much space, so you could consider uninstalling!

> Every hard disk is too small if you
>   just wait long enough. TreeSize Free
>   tells you where precious space has
>   gone to. TreeSize Free can be started
>   from the context menu of a folder or
>   drive and shows you the size of this
>   folder, including its subfolders. You
>   can expand this folder in
>   Explorer-like style and you will see
>   the size of every subfolder. Scanning
>   is done in a thread, so you can
>   already see results while TreeSize
>   Free is working. The space, which is
>   wasted by the file system, can be
>   displayed and the results can be
>   printed in a report.

[image]

Comment: +1 for TreeSize or alternatives like WinDirStat. Helped me get back few gigabytes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [ATF Cleaner](http://majorgeeks.com/ATF_Cleaner_d4949.html).

It's portable and easy to use...

Answer (score 0):

**[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)** is the best, plus with the command lines, you can have it scheduled to automatically keep your PC clean. This is what I do, I believe in automation of maintenance...