# Windows Updates installation fails - has never happened before

Tags: windows, windows-update

I am running W2K3, have Windows auto update enabled and things have been running smoothly for a long time, but the last time I have OK'ed to install downloaded updates all of them have failed.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. First, close any opened Internet Explorer windows.
2. Locate and empty the folder C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download
3. Reboot and relaunch windows update

Answer (score 0):

When that happened to me, it was due to running out of disk space. I suggest checking your free disk space. If this is the problem, you might want to read the answers to "[what is the best file utility cleanup tool for windows xp?](https://superuser.com/questions/59857/what-is-the-best-file-utility-cleanup-tool-for-windows-xp)".